# ReactJS - onSubmit function not being executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've been trying to implement a SignUp Component for my e-commerce project but the 'handleSubmit' function isn't being executed at all when i click on the 'Sign Up' Button i.e the CustomButton Component.I'm using Firebase for authentication and as well as for the Database and any help on this would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      displayName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: ""
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );

      await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });

      this.setState({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: ""
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="sign-up">
        <h2 className="title">I do not have an account</h2>
        <span>Sign up with your email and password</span>
        <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="displayName"
            value={displayName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Display Name"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Email"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Password"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="password"
            name="confirmPassword"
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Confirm Password"
            required
          />
          <CustomButton type="submit">SIGN UP</CustomButton>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `CustomButton` look like? Show the code for that component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind handleSubmit in the constructor:

```js
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        displayName : '',
        email : '',
        password : '',
        confirmPassword : ''
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Read [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) to find out why you should bind event handlers in React.

## EDIT

Since you're using arrow function, the above solution might not work.

I think the problem is with `CustomButton`. I think it should look like this one:

```js
class CustomButton {

   render() {
      return (
        <SomeTag>
          <button type="submit" someProps={someValue}>
              {someTitle}
          </button>
          // or <input type="submit" />
        </SomeTag>
      );
   };
}
```

The point is, the real button or input tag should have "submit" type attribute.

If you want to pass type attribute to button or input tag you can do as the following (in CustomButton.jsx):

```js
<button someProp={someValue} {...props}>
   {someTitle}
</button>
```

Comment: Wait, you don't have to `bind` anything - OP is using `arrow function expressions`.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't make any difference using `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);` :/

Comment: @NotKev Hi, I updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: @bravemaster I just passed `handleSubmit` as props and then used the `onClick` function to execute it. Thanks alot  dude

Comment: @bravemaster what you did for that `CustomButton` component is very wrong

Comment: Can I know the reason? Passing arbitrary props?

Comment: @bravemaster `class CustomButton { render(<someTag>...</someTag>) }` that's not valid syntax and/or component. `class CustomButton extends React.Component { render() { return <someTag>...</someTag>; } }` - that's more like it

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'm using React hooks and confused syntax with it. Updated